# Ionic 5 to change Android minSdkVersion from 21 to version 23

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator, capacitor

I'm trying out Ionic 5 App on android Emulator.

command: `ionic capacitor run android -l --external`

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0]
```

Emulator:

```
Name: Pixel_2_API_27 CPU/ABI:
Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 27) 
Skin: pixel_2 
SD Card: 100M
```

Package.json:

```
"@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2"
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.34.0",
```

Before on **Ionic 4** we could change the config.xml

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

but in **Ionic 5** I'm not sure how to change it.

Comment: Just a note. `capacitor` doesn't use the `config.xml` file. For `android` builds with `capacitor` you can changes values from `variables.gradle`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Capacitor you manage the `minSdkVersion` from gradle on:

`yourProjectName\android\variables.gradle`

I hope this be useful to you.

Comment: Another #IonicGotcha. Thanks.

Comment: Also the Application ID and Application Name, which previously were controlled by config.xml are now, with Capacitor, controlled by capacitor.config.json.